# Login com CPF com NodeJs, ReactJs e MongoDB

Tags: node.js, api, react, mongodb, react-router

Bom eu construí uma API para cadastros no banco mongodb remoto (Atlas), consigo cadastrar, o intuito é oferecer um formulário para os dados do usuário(Nome, cpf, telefone) e depois fazer o CPF, feito o login o usuário deverá ser direcionado para uma pagina (dashboard) com o nome do usuário e seus dados.
No Insomnia eu pego o cpf via req.body `{"cpf":"241545444"}` e dá certo, retorna o meu usuário com aquele cpf, isso porque usei `user.findOne({req.body.cpf})` ṕara filtrar o primeiro usuário com aquele CPF:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema está quando eu tento fazer que esses dados apareçam no frontend com ReactJS,
usei o axios para requeri a Api, montei o fomulário de Login, e pedir para me retorna os dados do usuário baseado no dados do input (cpf), armazeno esse dados no State e SetState mas esses dados não são comparados com o da api e retorna um `requeste.data null`...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço pra pegar o cpf do inout comparar com o da api e retorna um objeto assim  como mostra no insomnia ???
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite, Mateus! Pelo que você descreveu, o máximo que eu posso responder sem ter os detalhes do erro do debug do navegador é o seguinte: está faltando a utilização do Cors no seu BackEnd, por que por padrão o Backend não responde requisições de um domínio não permitido, por isso, quando você tenta fazer uma requisição pelo Axios no Front-end, ele retorna NULL. O Cors é uma especificação que permite que você (dono do seu Backend) diga para ele quais domínios (ou seja, quais Front-ends) podem consumir os dados da sua API. Isso se for realmente esse erro, se você puder enviar log que aparece no Console, poderia confirmar essa hipótese.

Aqui um [Link ensinando como adicionar o Cors ao seu Backend em Node e Express, caso esse seja realmente o problema](https://github.com/expressjs/cors)

Comment: No Backend estou usando o core ```express().use(cors())```. Tal que estou cadastrando os usuários pela interface feita com ReactJs usando a api, só não estou conseguindo fazer a parte de login.